# Errors while using PyDub. How do I fix?

Tags: python, ffprobe, pydub

I am trying to make a DAW, but I keep getting  the same error whenever I try to run the code.
Also my file cannot be found, even though I put in the right path.
Code:

```
import getpass
from pydub import AudioSegment
username=getpass.getuser()
song=AudioSegment.from_mp3('C:\\Users\\sanch\\Documents\\Cryo DAW\\bad_patty!.mp3')
```

Error:

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Users\sanch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pydub\utils.py", line 170
    warn("Couldn't find ffmpeg or avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg, but may not work", RuntimeWarning)
RuntimeWarning: Couldn't find ffmpeg or avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg, but may not work

Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Users\sanch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pydub\utils.py", line 198
    warn("Couldn't find ffprobe or avprobe - defaulting to ffprobe, but may not work", RuntimeWarning)
RuntimeWarning: Couldn't find ffprobe or avprobe - defaulting to ffprobe, but may not work
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/sanch/Documents/Python Projects/Cryo DAW.py", line 4, in <module>
    song=AudioSegment.from_mp3('C:\\Users\\sanch\\Documents\\Cryo DAW\\bad_patty!.mp3')
  File "C:\Users\sanch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pydub\audio_segment.py", line 796, in from_mp3
    return cls.from_file(file, 'mp3', parameters=parameters)
  File "C:\Users\sanch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pydub\audio_segment.py", line 728, in from_file
    info = mediainfo_json(orig_file, read_ahead_limit=read_ahead_limit)
  File "C:\Users\sanch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pydub\utils.py", line 274, in mediainfo_json
    res = Popen(command, stdin=stdin_parameter, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
  File "C:\Users\sanch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 951, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\sanch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 1420, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Pls help!

Comment: It's not your audio file that isn't found, it's `ffmpeg`.  That module is a thin wrapper around the `ffmpeg` tools, which you apparently do not have.  You'll need to install `ffmpeg`, and probably need to tell the module where to find it.

Answer (score 0):

- If you are on Linux simply install **ffmpeg** and **libavcodec-extra**:

  - ```
    $ sudo apt-get install ffmpeg libavcodec-extra
    ```
- then install pydub library and your errors will be fixed:

  - ```
    $ pip3 install pydub
    ```